# Echo Execute PHP Code

Tags: php, echo

Is it possible to execute PHP code in echo?  I need this to finish my work, but everything I try seems to be fruitless; I often bump to either blank browser page or some errors.

It does not need to be with echo func. Here is example of the code I would like to compile. Just a sample nothing flashy. Echo is just example, I would like to put more complex and advanced code at echo's place but I would like to start from simple stuff like that.

```
<?php $code = "<?php echo '123'; ?>" echo $code; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to echo PHP code?  What is your real goal here?  Why can't you just do `<?php echo '123'; ?>`?  This *is* possible, but I don't want to suggest the solution, because there's probably a better way.

Comment: Did you read what i wrote ? I want to substitute this echo with more advance Code. And i would like the first echo to print the result of the code inside in the browser ! thats my goal. I wont go in deatails of mine work atm as its irellevant And maybe your solution is ????

Comment: I was trying to ask *why* you have code as a string.  That's not good practice.

Comment: Yes , but isnt it possable to answer my Q?

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing, the only answer is `eval()`, which (as you know) you shouldn't use.

Comment: I think we might be unclear on what you're asking. Can you tell us specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes i am trying to encode part of my work . I would like to encode the script then i will make decoder which will take the script decode it and then run it and show it in browser all in the same .php !

Comment: @user2742982: PHP encoders already exist, why reinvent the wheel?  Have you tried any already?

Comment: I further updated my answer based on these comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is....an epic fail catastrophe. But for whatever reason, I'm answering...  You would need to use `eval()`. But don't do it. Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Perhaps you just need to use `include 'path/to/file/with/my/code';`. Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Based on your comments, I think you're actually looking for this:
`echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(__FILE__));`

That will display the php code that ran. You could search for that line and remove it before displaying. You could even write a function to look at all of the included files and add them to a $variable to be displayed, using the same logic.

Comment: "If `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." --Rasmus Lerdorf (creator of PHP)

Comment: Really Eval ? Can you write simple code to show what you mean ! I know what eval is and what threats it poses. My code is not even related to this !

Comment: @user2742982: How is your code not related to this?  It's *exactly* related to it.

Comment: Nvm , can you post a Sample of what you mean so i can take a look ?

Comment: @user2742982 `$code = 'your php code'; eval( $code );` <-- As others have said, _bad idea_, but there you go.  You may need to modify it depending on whether you are just producing output, or looking for a return value or whatnot.

Comment: See my updated answer about `include`.

Comment: Ok will take a look , Thx to watcher tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Php is only executed on the serverside, so when you try your echo code, you are saying print this code. If you want your code to validate/run logic after it has been server from the server, i would recommend looking into javascript and AJAX requests.

Good luck :)

Comment: He didn't say anything about running after page load. If he has the code there as a string already, he could just as soon have `eval()`'d it. However, this whole point is moot since he could just as soon have made the actual code available in his script and used it.

Comment: Eval is working as i wanted thx. I know the risks Thx